# EPPlus - InsertColumn function does not copy the style properly

Tags: c#, .net, excel, .net-core, epplus

After some experiences with MS Interop Excel I switched to EPPlus 4.5.3.3. So far I am very happy with the results.
However, when I want to insert a new column in an already existing Excel file, only the style of the first cell gets copied.

I also found out during my investigation that there were already similar issues:
https://epplus4.rssing.com/chan-7547932/all_p76.html

Also, there seems to be a bug for InsertRows:
https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/288

Is there any known bug for the InsertColumn function? If so, is there any workaround? If not, what am I missing in my code?

My code looks as follows:

```
            FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputName);
            ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
            ExcelWorkbook wb = excel.Workbook;
            ExcelWorksheet y = wb.Worksheets.First();
            y.InsertColumn(1, 1, 2); 
            y.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Test1";
            y.Cells[2, 1].Value = "Test2";
            y.Cells[3, 1].Value = "Test3";
```

The first screenshot shows the expected result:

[image: Expected result]

While this is my actual result:

[image: actual result]

Thanks a lot for any suggestions :)

Comment: when I open my Excel template and add a new column by simply typing some characters in it, the style from the previous column/cells gets used. However, neither adding new values via "InsertColumn" nor by simply adding them with "y.Cells[x,y].Value" replicates the previous style when doing this via EPPlus. What is EPPlus doing different here that it somehow overrides the usual behavior of Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using a table which started from column B (originally "A" column - before adding the column above). When adding an additional column, the table was not expanded to the new range. By changing back the table to a normal range, everything is working as expected and the style is copied.

When using MSFT Interop Excel, this was automatically handled by simply adding any content in a new column.